# How to add values in dictionaries together

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary, merge

I've got two dictionaries from JSON API and they contain another dictionary in the dictionary.It looks something like this:

```
dict1 = {"abc": 0, "efg": {"123": 10, "456": 5}}
dict2 = {"abc": 10, "efg": {"123": 7, "456": 3}}
```

I would like to add those values in the two dictionaries together, and the result would look like this

```
result = {"abc": 10, "efg": {"123": 17, "456": 8}}
```

How can I get the result?
I have tried the collections.Counter but that have a limitation of only work for positive int , I have tried to use the following code

```
result = {key: dict1.get(key, 0) + dict2.get(key, 0)
          for key in set(dict1) | set(dict2)}
```

but that just work for normal int and not a dictionary in dictionary

Comment: Please ask a specific question about a specific error you have. This site is not meant for simply providing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add them in a recursive function like this:

```
dict1 = {"abc": 0, "efg": {"123": 10, "456": 5}}
dict2 = {"abc": 10, "efg": {"123": 7, "456": 3}}

def add(dict1,dict2):
    for key in dict2: 
        if key in dict1:
            if not isinstance(dict1[key],dict):
                dict2[key] = dict2[key] + dict1[key]
            else:
                add(dict1[key],dict2[key])

add(dict1,dict2)

print(dict2)
```

Output:

```
{'abc': 10, 'efg': {'123': 17, '456': 8}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in the past. Turned out to be a bit more complex than expected especially if you need to deal with nested dict not having all the same keys.

Here is the function I wrote at the time. It is not the most readable code, but it worked well for me.

```
def merge_dict(dictA, dictB):
    """(dict, dict) => dict
    Merge two dicts, if they contain the same keys, it sums their values.
    Return the merged dict.
    
    Example:
        dictA = {'any key':1, 'point':{'x':2, 'y':3}, 'something':'aaaa'}
        dictB = {'any key':1, 'point':{'x':2, 'y':3, 'z':0, 'even more nested':{'w':99}}, 'extra':8}
        merge_dict(dictA, dictB)
        
        {'any key': 2,
         'point': {'x': 4, 'y': 6, 'z': 0, 'even more nested': {'w': 99}},
         'something': 'aaaa',
         'extra': 8}
    """
    r = {}

    common_k = [k for k in dictA if k in dictB]

    for k, v in dictA.items():
        # add unique k of dictA
        if k not in common_k:
            r[k] = v

        else:
            # add inner keys if they are not containing other dicts
            if type(v) is not dict:
                if k in dictB:
                    r[k] = v + dictB[k]
            else:
                # recursively merge the inner dicts
                r[k] = merge_dict(dictA[k], dictB[k])

    # add unique k of dictB
    for k, v in dictB.items():
        if k not in common_k:
            r[k] = v

    return r
```